# JasperReport Libraries for Netbeans

Tags: java, jaspersoft-studio

I'm trying to integrate JasperReport with NetBeans, though I'm not finding the necessary libraries. I downloaded the Jasper library files at the following link:

https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library/releases

But some libs like iText, which I know is required are not in the package and I do not know where to find them. If anyone can tell me what libraries are needed and where I can find them, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will pay to read your own link because you can find all the requirements and links to each required packages on the website you linked in your question.

Just go to the [Requirements] section: https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-requirements

**Note: For the specific version of iText required, you can find it here**: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext/2.1.7 and you will also need a copy of the bouncy castle jar (linked to on the same page)

Copy and paste from the above link

> **JRE**
>
> Java Runtime Environment 6.0 or higher
>
> **Commons**
>
> Jakarta Commons BeanUtils Component (version 1.7 or later)
>      http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/beanutils/
>
> Jakarta Commons Collections Component (version 2.1 or later)
>      http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/collections/
>
> Jakarta Commons Javaflow (Sandbox version)
>      http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/sandbox/javaflow/
>
> Jakarta Commons Logging Component (version 1.0 or later)
>      http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/logging/
>
> **JRXML**
>
> JAXP 1.1 XML Parser
>      Jakarta Commons Digester Component (version 1.7 or later)
>      http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/digester/
>
> One of the following for report compilation, depending on the report compiler used:
>
> - Eclipse JDT Java Compiler (recommended) http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/
> - JDK 1.4 or higher
> - Jikes Compiler http://jikes.sourceforge.net
> - Groovy (version 1.5.5 or later) http://groovy.codehaus.org
> - BeanShell (version 2.0 beta 4 or later) http://www.beanshell.org
>
> **JDBC**
>
> JDBC 2.0 Driver
>
> **PDF**
>
> iText - Free Java-PDF library by Bruno Lowagie and Paulo Soares (version 1.3.1 or later) http://www.lowagie.com/iText/
>
> **XLS**
>
> Jakarta POI (version 3.0.1 or later) http://jakarta.apache.org/poi/
>
> JExcelApi (version 2.6 or later) http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/
>
> **Charts**
>
> JFreeChart (1.0.0 or later) http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/
>
> JCommon - required by JFreeChart http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/
>
> Batik SVG Toolkit (1.7 or later) - required when rendering charts as SVG http://xmlgrap hics.apache.org/batik/